# sublime text 3 code folder short cut key definition is not working

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am trying to use code folding command, but the short-cut is not working. I have to use menu, which is not convenient.

What does the "," mean in short cut? I tried the short cut on both side of the ",". They all not working.  command + K is not working.

[image]

I think the reason is there is conflict here:

[image]

Then I try to configure a unique short cut key, which is also not woriking. Here is my configure

```
[
    {"keys":["super+;"],"command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file":"Packages/User/Semicolon.sublime-macro"}},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "open_in_browser"},
    { "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "goto_definition" }, 
    { "keys": ["command+9"], "command": "fold_level_9" } // here is the definition

]
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong? 
How do I make the code folding short-cut work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> means you hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, release both buttons, then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>. Sublime allows these compound keyboard commands, and recognizes it as different from <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> alone. Try removing your custom shortcut keys (as they may be interfering with other commands) and seeing if the built-in commands work now.